# Spring’s embedded H2 datasource and DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT

Tags: java, spring, h2

For unit tests (call them integration tests if you want) I have configured an embedded database in my Spring config like so:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema_h2.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

Now, when running the tests from the command line, they work fine, but I get some errors at the end (harmless, but irritating):

```
WARN  2013-03-25 12:20:22,656 [Thread-9] o.s.j.d.e.H2EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer 'Could not shutdown embedded database'
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-170]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329) ~[h2-1.3.170.jar:1.3.170]
    ...
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean.destroy(EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean.java:65) [spring-jdbc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:238) [spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
```

Now the tip contained in the exception is fine in general, but how do I add this attribute to the embedded datasource? Do I have to expand it, configure it by hand so to speak, to add such *‘advanced’* features?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Specify parameter in JDBC url [jdbc:h2:~/test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#do_not_close_on_exit)

Also for in-memory test database I suggest you to add `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`, like this:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:alm;MODE=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
```

To add JDBC connection url to `embedded-dababase` change it to:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" ignore-failures="DROPS">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema_h2.sql" />
 </jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Comment: I found this much in the H2 documentation. You did not say how to add that to `<jdbc:embedded-database />`.

Comment: Just to be clear, the updated answer is stating that it cannot be used with `embedded-dababase`?  You need to use a datasource bean and `initialize-database`?

Comment: From my understanding, `mem` in the url makes the h2 embedded

Comment: Is it something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806153/spring-tests-are-closing-embedded-database-multiple-times ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as Michael Piefel's one and tried to implement the solution that Michail Nikolaev explained.
but it did not work, somehow spring-batch, then, where are the metadata JOB_* tables are.
So, as the version of `spring-jdbc` used by my application is 3.0.5 and increasing the `spring-framework` one enters in conflict with `dwr` (i use it in my app) it's a `geo` localization based on spring, `dwr` and `gmaps api`.
I downloaded the `spring-jdbc 4.0.3` release and get from it the `H2EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer.class` who has `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE` by default and replace with it the one on the `spring-jdbc 3.0.5` Release and deploy-it in the war file and it works, the shutdown of the `VM` didn't provoke the closing of the in-memory database.

Hope this unusual solution helps if other people like me wouldn't be able to implement the other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it was because I forgot to add the annotation @Entity on one of my entities. I add it and it work now !
I hope this helps someone.